# Testing @current_user method using RSpec

Tags: ruby, unit-testing, rspec, authlogic

I've been trying to do this for a couple of days now, but I can't figure it out. I have the following code in my controller:

```
@some_object = @current_user.some_method
```

In my spec, I want to attach a should_receive hook on that method, but I can't make it work. I've tried all of these, but none of them work:

```
assigns[:current_user].should_receive(:some_method).at_least(:once) # expected 1, got 0
User.should_receive(:some_method).at_least(:once) # expected 1, got 0
```

How is the correct way of testing this? I'm running this in my spec, and login is working:

```
setup :activate_authlogic
...
UserSession.create(users(:rune))
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One example comes from the [Ruby on Rails Tutorial](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/). Rather than setting and reading `@current_user` directly, it defines two helper methods:

```
def current_user=(user)
  @current_user = user
end

def current_user
  @current_user
end
```

Later, they access this method in the tests using the `controller` method:

```
def test_sign_in(user)
  controller.current_user = user
end
```

Using this methodology, you should be able to use

```
controller.current_user.should_receive(:some_method).at_least(:once)
```

Comment: Hmmm. I have defined that method, but it's defined in ApplicationController as a :helper_method, so it's accessible in all controllers and views. But it's not available for RSpec:
`private method `current_user' called for #<IdeasController:0x103c87180>`

Comment: For those particular helpers they included them into `ApplicationController` via `include SessionsHelper`. You could also probably use `controller.send(:current_user)` to get the object.

Answer (score 2):

You can’t call something like in the controllers:

```
expect(current_user).to be_present
expect(user_signed_in?).to be_true
```

So to do so, you can do this :

```
module ControllerMacros
  def current_user
    user_session_info = response.request.env['rack.session']['warden.user.user.key']
    if user_session_info
      user_id = user_session_info[0][0]
      User.find(user_id)
    else
      nil
    end
  end

  def user_signed_in?
    !!current_user
  end
end
```

You can either include the ControllerMacros in the top of the controller spec or include it in the spec_helper.rb like so :

```
RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.include ControllerMacros, type: :controller
end
```